# protocol buffer lite versus regular protocol buffer

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers

I've been investigating c++ serialization frameworks will small footprint and good performance. I've found this thread

[c++ network serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623791/c-network-serialization)

which basically suggest to use the lite version of protocol buffers. It is not clear from [this page](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite.html) what are the specific features of the lite version

my question is; what features do you lose when sticking to protocol buffers lite?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The "lite" version is not able to serialize to or from <s>[`iostream`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.h), or</s> "`FileDescriptor`", and it cannot use the `Reflection` feature (although [it does use refection](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6463#issuecomment-554704628)), and... a scattering of other features.

My advice is to just use the lite version until you come across a feature that requires the full version. It is very easy to switch from one to the other.

If you need to see a list of what the lite version lacks, I recommend browsing `<google/protobuf/message.h>`. Basically everything in that include file is exclusive to the full version. (`<google/protobuf/message_lite.h>` is `#include`d from the full version.)
Here's a link:
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/message.h

Comment: Don't forget to add `option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;` to your .proto files if you use the lite version.

Comment: Reading above comments is an emotional roller coaster.

Comment: Edited to reflect existence (at present) of `SerializeToOstream()` in `class MessageLite`

Comment: The Lite version does not support the [protobuf text format](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/textformat-spec/#working-with-the-format-programmatically) (since it seems to require reflection as well).